# In MYSQL/PHP how would I delete from ID 1 and insert data to ID 5

Tags: php, mysql, database

[image]

This is how my table is setup. I want to add in a new height and then delete that data at ID 1 (2.0). So it keeps leap frogging when inserting in new data. This is so I can keep up to only 5 records at a time.

Sorry, I'm very new to MYSQL/PHP.

Comment: What do you mean leap-frogging. Assuming `id` is an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key you will not get `id` as 1 on a subsequent insert

Comment: why don't you use an update?

Comment: Create and manage a new field. ID column must let as auto increment value.

Comment: Aiming to keep the table to a certain length should probably be handled by the application. You will need to do `SELECT COUNT(*)` and then an insert only if below 5 - this will want to be a single transaction probably.

Comment: I assume he is talking about rotating entrie values

Comment: I wanted to delete 2.0, and then insert in data. Then I'd delete 2.4 because it was next in line and insert in new data. Keep the maximum of entries to 5.

Am I looking at this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert new data:

```
INSERT INTO table (height) VALUES (xxx);
```

Delete the pair (1,2.0):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id=1;
```

OR... all together like this:

```
UPDATE table SET height=xxx WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: 'Rolling delete' might look like: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);`

Comment: Yes, looks nice like this.

Comment: Now how do I reset the ID increments?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

Comment: I think I'm confused or thinking about this in the wrong way. I basically just need to insert in new data but only hold up to 5 entries. like the picture I had. Every time you insert in new data the last one will be deleted, and so on. I just thought you'd want to not increment the ID's every time you did. I'm so new to this...

Comment: Let me see if I get it: every the time you insert new data, which one will be deleted, the one with id=1 or id=5?

Comment: id = 1. So I'd always keep a history of 4 after the newly inserted data. And I'm not even sure what ID's are... or why I'd want to increment them or reset them... so this is who you're dealing with =D

Comment: And do you want to keep the ID=1 for the new item inserted or it will get ID=6?

Comment: Is it bad for the ID to increment really far? If so, I would think it would be wise to just keep it to ID 1 through 5. New data is inserted at 5. ID 1 data is delete, and everything shifts down ID's.

Comment: This is what I have so far:

`
$rand = rand(1,10);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wave_data (height) VALUES ($rand)");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM wave_data ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
`

Comment: Well it is important in order to select the row to be emptied.

If the id is about to be kept, you can do: `UPDATE table SET height=xxx WHERE id=1`.

Comment: Sure! But you should change the order: first delete the first, then insert the new. This way you won't exceed the 5 rows anytime.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET height=xxx WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)`. The Select... gets the last one, ie, the one with greatest ID number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24595/discussion-between-tom-and-fedorqui)

Answer (score 2):

for the delete, something like this might work better:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5)
```

essentially delete from the table where the id doesn't match the last 5 ids inserted. This also works when there are less than 5 entries in the database, nothing would get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the first item do:

```
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'd first of course say a little prayer.  Prefer to be a little more explicit with deletes.

Comment: do you want to delete a random row?

Comment: If you want only the lowest id just add an order by: `DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1`